# Is there a way of adding an Amazon EC2 Instance onto Finder?

Tags: macos, sftp, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, finder

Hey is it possible to virtually mount an EC2 Instance in finder? I'm trying to eliminate the use of an external SFTP client (I use Terminus at the moment) and I was wondering if it was possible if I could just natively use finder instead.

Right now I'm running

```
ftps://root@[IPAddressOfEC2Instance]
```

Although it's asking for a password, is there a way to specify a .pem file instead?

Comment: If your question cannot be answered here, it might be worth posting it over at https://apple.stackexchange.com/. In case you do that, make sure you post the link here so that this question can be closed if appropriate

Answer (score 1):

Try using SFTP (which is using SSH) and you will be able to authenticate using SSH private key (.pem file).

Not sure what FTP client you are using. Cyberduck2 may be an option.